# IconView with one scrollbar

Tags: python, scrollbar, pygtk

Good day!
I need an IconView widget with vertical (only) scrollbar. I put my IconView into ScrolledWindow and turned off the horizontal scrollbar. This way:

```
liststore = gtk.ListStore(gtk.gdk.Pixbuf)
for item in gtk.stock_list_ids():
    liststore.append([self.render_icon(item, gtk.ICON_SIZE_DIALOG)])
iconview = gtk.IconView(liststore)
iconview.set_pixbuf_column(0)
scrolledwindow = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
scrolledwindow.add_with_viewport(iconview) 
scrolledwindow.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_NEVER, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
```

And when I stretch the window out icons within the widget spread in width. However, when I shrink the window icons don't spread in height, they stay beyond the window's border instead and I cannot get them because there is no horizontal scrollbar.

It seems like I do something wrong, but how to do it right? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should use

```
scrolledwindow.add(iconview)
```

instead of 'add_with_viewport'